# Thread lock error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a timer who run in a runloop, the problem is when the timer end's and the user scroll the page at the same time, the apps crash with the problem:

bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x18d9be60: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

this is the timer:

```
- (void)startTimer{

    NSThread* timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startTimerThread) object:nil]; //Create a new thread

    [timerThread start]; //start the thread
}

-(void) startTimerThread
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [repeatingTimerEtape invalidate];

    NSString * temps; 

    if (questionCircuit) {

        temps = [[Mission singletonMission].circuitTerrain valeurChampEtapeCircuitEnCours:@"et_temps_etape" :FALSE];
    }
    else {
        temps = [[Mission singletonMission].histoireTerrain valeurChampQuestion:@"hi_temps_etape" :FALSE];
    }

    if (!b_Pause) {
        [dateComp setHour:0];
        [dateComp setMinute:[[FonctionUtile gauche:temps :2] intValue]];
        [dateComp setSecond:[[FonctionUtile droite:temps :2] intValue]];
    }
    else {
        b_Pause = FALSE;
    }

    self.repeatingTimerEtape = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabelTimerEtape:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

### Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread.

You started a thread then did stuff on it that should only be done on the main thread or the "web thread".

Most likely in your updateLabelTimerEtape: method.  Look at the backtrace to know for sure.

Also, `valeurChampQuestion:::` is a horrible method name.  Don't make methods that have arguments that lack a description.  `valeurChampQuestion:isSelected:` would be better (replace `isSelected:` with a better description -- since others can't tell what it should be from that line of code, that is confirmation that bare arguments are bad).

Comment: There isn't enough information to say more;  you need to post the crash log.